# Is there any useful necessary and sufficient condition for $x\in S$ to be an accumulation point of $M$? (Kazuo Matsuzaka's book about topology)

Tags: general-topology

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> Definition:
> Let $(S,\mathcal{O}$) be a topological space.
> Let $M\subset S$.
> If $x\in\overline{M-\{x\}}$, then $x$ is called an accumulation point of $M$.

Is there any useful easy-to-understand necessary and sufficient condition for $x\in S$ to be an accumulation point of $M$?

My attempt:
I intuitively wondered that the following equality holds.
But the following equality doesn't hold:
$\{x\in S\mid x\text{ is an accumulation point of }M\}=\operatorname{Int}M\cup (\operatorname{Bd}M-\{x\in S\mid x\text{ is an isolated point of }M\}).$
If $\mathcal{O}=2^S$, then $x$ is an interior point of $\{x\}$, but $x$ is not an accumulation point of $\{x\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in S$ is an accumulation point of $M$ iff every open set containing $x$ contains a point of $M$ other than $x$ i.e $$\forall O\in \mathcal{O} \text{ and } x\in O \implies  \mathcal{O}\cap M\setminus \{x\}\neq \emptyset$$

This is a necessary and sufficient condition of a limit point.

---

Let $M'$$=\{x\in S : x \text{ is an accumulation point of } M\}$ and $\text{Iso}(M) = \{x\in M : x\notin M'\}$

Hence $M'=\overline{M}\setminus \text{Iso}(M)$

$\overline{M}=M^\circ \cup\partial M$

$M'=(M^\circ \cup\partial M)\setminus \text{Iso}( M) $

This is the result you want but this doesn't seem  " **useful easy-to-understand necessary and sufficient condition for $  x\in S $ to be an accumulation point of $M$** "

---

$\mathcal{O}=2^S$ then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $\{x\}$ because $x\in\text{Iso}(\{x\})$ .

But it is even easy to check by definition $x\in \{x\}\in \mathcal{O}$ and $\{x\}$ contains no point other than $x$ itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer!